# How to get foreign key's method used in Laravel Eloquent Relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem with how to get the method name that was used in other models.

There is a list of models and some of them have used different method name on its relationship to other models.

For example, I have a model name of **Member Rate Detail** wherein it belongs to **Member Rate** model. The method that connects from **Member Rate Detail** to **Member Rate** is `head()` method.

Here is the sample code for head() method:

```
public function head()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MemberRate::class, 'member_rate_head_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

And for **Customer Detail** model it belongs to **Customer** model. And the connector method name that was used is `group()`

Here is the sample code for group():

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'head_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
}
```

So the problem is I don't know if this model is using head() or group() or another method name.

Is there a Laravel Relationship concept way which can get a list or an array type of its foreign key's method used?

I'm expected to get the method name so that I can direct it to its instance class.

For example:

```
$memberRateDetail->getForeignMethod()->created_by;

**OR**

$customerDetail->getForeignMethod()->created_by;
```

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score -1):

No, there are not unless you declare them yourself.

Let's say you declare a method in your all your models where you declare the method for the class foreign relation. You can also implement it as an interface.

You can also just use code hinting if you have a good IDE, declaring a relation in PHP docs as `* @property Collection head` can help too.